# Fastest way to vertically bind (rbind / bind_rows) two large data frames with many columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

I'm specifically interested in an efficient solution for rbinding two data frames with the same columns in the same order. I'm trying to stay within the tibble/dplyr framework to avoid continually converting objects to different classes, but I can't seem to find a method close to the performance of `data.table`.

Example:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(data.table)

# create tibble and data.table
tb2 <- tb <- as_tibble(matrix(data=rep(1:5, 20000), ncol=20000, nrow=5, dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('c',1:20000))))
dt2 <- dt <- as.data.table(tb)

system.time(temp1 <- rbind(tb, tb2))       # 0.2s
system.time(temp2 <- bind_rows(tb, tb2))   # 31s
system.time(temp3 <- rbind(dt, dt2))       # 0.02s
```

Is there anything within `base` or `dplyr` that matches the performance of data.table in this instance?

Comment: Why not use data.table? You can still do everything you would do with the data.frame, right?

Comment: `tb[(nrow(tb) + 1):(nrow(tb) + nrow(tb2)), ] <- tb2` is pretty fast, though not as fast as data.table.